# Using set operations to conditionally reduce a set to the empty set based on its contents

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given sets $X$ and $Y$, with $X \cap Y = \emptyset, X \neq \emptyset, Y \neq \emptyset$, is it possible to construct a series of set operations $f$ such that for all $Z \subseteq X$ with $Z \neq \emptyset$ , $f(Z \cup Y ) = \emptyset$ and $f(Y) = Y$?

An example of an $f$ that does not work is $f(A) = (A \cap X) \cup Y$, here I am demonstrating that $X$ and $Y$ may be used as constant expressions in $f$.

Comment: At the least, you must impose more restrictions on X and Y, as if one takes $X\subseteq  Y$, then your conclusion would be a contradiction unless $Y=\emptyset$.

Comment: I had in mind that $X \cap Y = \emptyset$, have stated that in the question now

Comment: What exactly is a "set operation"?

Comment: By "set operation" I mean unions, intersections, differences and complements

Comment: Only one of those operates on a single set, yet you have $f$ acting on only one set. That makes it very hard (impossible?) to come up with a set function that is not uniformly $\emptyset$, the entire "universe", or the identity or complement functions.

Comment: It looks like I am not being precise enough with my language to get my point across, let me try to explain in looser terms and maybe you can help me to make it more formal. With $f$, I am interested in whether I can manipulate the input set in such a way that when the input set contains a subset of $X$, the output will be the empty set and when it does not, the output is the input set. $f(A)$ is allowed to perform operations like $X \cap A$ and so can "fill in" one of the arguments to $\cap$ with a constant, where constants can be built from $X$ and $Y$